# Attempted unsupported operation with Raster Catalog in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster-catalog, arcgis-10.4

I recently installed ArcGIS 10.4 on my Windows 10 machine. I upgraded from ArcGIS 10.3.1.

After upgrading, I noticed when I add a raster catalog to a map and go to the properties, it displays an error, and then the map crashes.

[image]

If anyone else has encountered this, any help will do.

I have submitted an error report to ESRI so I will wait to see as well if they respond.

Comment: I can't reproduce a crash following your steps. It might have something to do with your data. Tech Support is going to be your best bet in understanding this.

Comment: Can post the error from the Event Viewer?

Answer (score 1):

Since this is directly after an upgrade. I would rename your ESRI folder under your profile(...\AppData\Roaming\ESRI) and the default geodatabase(...\My Documents\ArcGIS).
I have seen consistent issues between versions and these folders and files.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. I apologize for not providing more details about the error. I ended up uninstalling ArcGIS through revo uninstaller as well as manually going through and deleting folders such as (...\AppData\Roaming\ESRI), uninstalled ArcHydro, and all third party extensions for ArcMap like SoilMart, and FDOT TranStat.  ... I reinstalled it and everything works now. So its one of those things probably like you said, the ESRI folder under profile.  Thanks again!